# How can i run a check in PHP to see if my MYSQL Stored Procedure ran correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm used to working with MSSQL but recently have had to use MYSQL, I know it is similar but the way things are done are confusing me slightly.

My question is after I have called a stored procedure (insert, update, select, delete) how can I do a check within PHP that the call was successful before returning data from my function?

CURRENT MYSQL (SELECT) call from PHP:

```
public function login($email){
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare('call loginUser(?)');
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        // if($stmt === false){
        //  return false;           HOW I CURRENTLY DO IT IN MSSQL
        // }
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $stmt->close();
        return json_encode(array("success"=>true));
    }
```

CURRENT MYSQL (INSERT) call from PHP:

```
public function registerUser($params){
        // Prepare and Bind
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare('call addUser(?,?,?,?,?)');
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $firstname, $surname, $displayname, $email, $password);

        $firstname = $params['firstname'];
        $surname = $params['surname'];
        $displayname = $params['firstname'] . ' ' . $params['surname'];
        $email = $params['email'];
        $password = password_hash($params['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        return json_encode(array("success"=>true));
    }
```

Comment: There exists a manual for PHP/MySQL. In this case see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware So just to clarify using the examples above, in the register function I would use $stmt->mysqli_stmt_affected_rows(); after the execute and use it within an if statement?

Comment: No. You can use the return value of `execute()` to see if it failed. The manual says: "Return Values: Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.". You can only use `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()` when the execution was successful. Note that the manual says nothing about the method you used for MSSQL, assuming this is also done with mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**execute** returns bool value, you can check it this way

```
if (! $stmt->execute()) { return false; }
```

Comment: for a select would i run $stmt->get_result() within the if statement?

Comment: Thanks, will check this when I get back

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public function registerUser($params= null){
    // Prepare and Bind
    if ($param==0) {
      echo '<script>alert(\'saved\')</script>';
      $stmt = $this->connection->prepare('call addUser(?,?,?,?,?)');
      $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $firstname, $surname, $displayname, $email, $password);

      $firstname = $params['firstname'];
      $surname = $params['surname'];
      $displayname = $params['firstname'] . ' ' . $params['surname'];
      $email = $params['email'];
      $password = password_hash($params['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
    }  

  }
```

Comment: I already check previously to see if the values are set, i need to know if the database side worked correctly